# How to set sublime as an external editor for jshell?

Tags: java, macos, editor, java-9, jshell

According to the jshell documentation:

> An alternative to editing at the command prompt is to use an external editor. This editor can be used to edit and create snippets, and is especially helpful for multiline snippets. You can configure JShell to use the editor of your choice.

So to implement this, i use the following commands:

```
jshell> /set editor sublime
|  Editor set to: sublime
```

And then, i tried to edit a snippet as follows:

```
jshell> /edit printName
|  Edit Error: process IO failure: Cannot run program "subllime": error=2, No such file or directory
```

But, i got the above error.
So is it the right way to set editor or something else is required?
I also tried to set Microsoft Word as the editor and specified the exact application path from the Application folder of Mac as follows:

```
jshell> /set editor /Users/karan.verma/Applications/Microsoft Word.app
|  Editor set to: /Users/karan.verma/Applications/Microsoft Word.app
```

Even, when i set the editor as "atom", i got the same results:

```
jshell> /set editor atom
|  Editor set to: atom
```

But still it shows the same error. Any help?

Comment: Plus one for the specific editors. Just try(assuming you have Atom installed) `/set editor atom` or `/set editor vi` these shall work.

Comment: Try `/set editor "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`
or 
`/set editor subl` if `subl` is already in the `PATH`

Comment: @Bless For me at least, these result in the same error as in the question.

Comment: @nullpointer even it did not worked for atom... Editing the question for the same.

Comment: @KayV Editing the question with operating system tag, I am though pretty sure this is not java-9, jshell specific. I've seem similar issues previously with git as well. Its the application recognition within your OS. for e.g if I simply type `atom` on my terminal, Atom opens up but the same doesn't work for Sublime. That seems to me the cause of why jshell is not able to open the Sublime editor for me at least. And you didn't come back with vim editor result, does that work fine?

Comment: @nullpointer @KayV Just tried on my mac. Can confirm that `/set editor subl -w` works for me.
Can you check if `sublime` or `subl` is in the `PATH`?
Also, does running `"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"` directly on the terminal start Sublime Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mightn't have worked for the OP. But worked for me. So, posting it here hoping it helps someone.

If you can type `subl` on a terminal and if Sublime Text opens (means `subl` is in `PATH`), try:

```
/set editor subl -w
```

If Sublime Text doesn't open on typing `subl` on terminal, but running `"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"` does open Sublime Text (means `subl` is not in `PATH`), try:

```
/set editor "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" -w
```

`-w` flag is to wait for the files to be closed in Sublime Text before returning.

Comment: The same applies to `Visual Studio Code`. The same `-w` flag is supported.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by supplying the full path to the sublime executable.  E.g on Windows.

`jshell> /set editor c:\sublime3\sublime_text.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify jshell editor via JSHELLEDITOR user/system variable

Answer (score 0):

In Windows set full path:

```
   jshell> /set editor C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

Please do not include inverted commas(" ") in path
In MacOs use inverted commas with path.

Answer (score -1):

Even i faced same problem as i was giving command

jshell > /set editor "/Applications/Sublime Text.app"

but what's missing is the exact path to bin directory in content folder of sublime.

**Solution:**

jshell > 
**/set editor "/Applications/SublimeText.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"**

Try this it will work 100%.

Comment: This will work in MacOs